# Работа с многомерными массивами. CUDA

Tags: массивы, cuda

Доброго времени суток!
Помогите разобраться с многомерными массивами в CUDA.
 1. Предположим, у нас есть массив 10х10, необходимо каждый элемент увеличить на, например, 10. Набросал такой код:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void Kernel(int *arr, size_t pitch) {

    int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    int *q = &arr[iy * pitch + ix];
    *q += 10;
}

int main() {
    int Arr[10][10];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
            Arr[i][j] = i + j;
            printf("%i\t", Arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int *dev_arr;

    cudaSetDevice(0);

    size_t pitch;
    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_arr, &pitch, 10*sizeof(int), 10);
    cudaMemcpy2D(dev_arr, 10*sizeof(int), Arr, pitch, 10*sizeof(int), 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    Kernel <<< 10, 10 >>> (dev_arr, pitch);
    cudaMemcpy2D(Arr, 10*sizeof(int), dev_arr, pitch, 10*sizeof(int), 10, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
            printf("%i\t",Arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0x0B;
}
```

Если коротко, не работает :( Где ошибка? Каким должен быть код?
2. Пусть у нас есть двумерный массив, строки которого разной длины. Как работать с таким?